# Bootstrap 4 input-group top is including the label

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm using some javascript to position an absolute element under my textbox.

However, when I try and get the offsetTop, I'm getting the top of the form-group instead of the top of the input.  I can't figure out why.

My html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div style="width: 300px;">
        <div class="form-group" style="position: relative;">
            <label>Start Date</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id='testInput' />
            </div>
        <div id='testOverlay'>Test</div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

and javascript:

```
(function test() {
    let inputEl = document.getElementById("testInput");
    let inputTop = inputEl.offsetTop;
    let inputHeight = inputEl.offsetHeight;
    console.log(inputTop, inputHeight);

    let overlayEl = document.getElementById("testOverlay");
    overlayEl.style.top = (inputTop + inputHeight) + "px";
})();
```

Here's a plunker that shows the problem:

https://plnkr.co/edit/yiEDl3Bo3I2e5vmv2BfF?p=preview

As you can see, the absolute element is in the middle of the input-group instead of below it like I would expect it to be.

Any help on why this is happening?

Edit: I found that overriding the input-group class to

```
.input-group {
    position: static;
}
```

fixes the issue.  I'm wondering if this is a bootstrap bug?

Comment: You create page for Yourself or just testing bootstrap 4 ? I will never understand people which use alpha release ... bootstrap 4 is more then year in alpha testing, so they must have big problem with it. Maybe check Bootstrap css to know how labels behave.